# using counter component button increase or decrease score twice

Tags: reactjs, jsx

this is my app componenet

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Player from './components/Player'
import React from 'react';


class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    players: [
      {
              name: "hamzeh",
              score: 0,
              id: 1
      },
      {
              name: "abbasi",
              score: 0,
              id: 2
      },
      {
              name: "younes",
              score: 0,
              id: 3
      },
    ]
  }

  changeScoreEventHandler = (index, delta) => {
    this.setState( prevState => {
        return {
            score: prevState.players[index].score += delta
        }
    })
  }

  removePlayerEventHandler = (id) => {
      this.setState( prevState => {
        return {
          players: prevState.players.filter( p => p.id !== id)
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-4 score-board">
          <h4 className="m-0"> score board for : { this.state.players.length }</h4>
        { this.state.players.map(
          (player, index) => (
            <Player 
              name={ player.name } 
              id={ player.id }
              key={ player.id.toString() }
              removePlayer={ this.removePlayerEventHandler }
              score={ player.score }
              changeScore={ this.changeScoreEventHandler }
              index={ index }
              />
          )
        )}
        
        </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the player component

```
import React from 'react'
import Counter from './Counter'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Player = (props) => {
        return (
                <div className="player d-block px-2">
                        <Button className="btn btn-danger d-inline mx-1" onClick={ () => props.removePlayer(props.id) } > R </Button>
                <span className="d-inline w-25 align-middle pl-2" >{ props.name }</span>
                <Counter 
                        score={ props.score }
                        changeScore={ props.changeScore }  
                        index={ props.index }      
                />
                </div>
        )
}


export default Player
```

and this is my counter component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'


const Counter = (props) => {

    let index = props.index
    return (
        <div className="counter d-inline w-50">
            <Button className="btn btn-primary decrement" onClick={() => props.changeScore(index, -1) }> - </Button>
                <span className="player-score mx-4">{ props.score}</span>
            <Button className="btn btn-danger increment" onClick={ () => props.changeScore(index, 1) }> + </Button>
        </div>
    )

    };

export default Counter;
```

i have these 3 components each time i increment from Counter component state goes up by 2
i have 2 question 1- why?
and 2- how can i access something like players[index].score: in setState instead of score:

somehow i think setState trigger twice i check the code but i can't find anything wrong about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setState` in `changeScoreEventHandler` is slightly malformed compared to the original state object. That way you're creating a new `score` property at the root level AND adding the score to the player element at the same time (which is also not allowed since it is supposed to be immutable).

From `setState` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated.

You can change that part like so:

```
  changeScoreEventHandler = (index, delta) => {
    const players = this.state.players.slice()
    players[index].score += delta
    this.setState({ players })
  }
```

Comment: check it, it works, and i get the logic behind it, tnx

Comment: the only question remains is how to do it with prevState